# reference error on javascript function using ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax

i´m using ajax to use a keyword search on a mysql database, and when results are coming i want to show options as href with an onclick function, the search works fine, but when i click on any option i get a reference error on my firebug, this is the code:
index.php

```
 <html>

<body>
    <style>
        #displayDiv {
            background-color: #ffeeaa;
            width: 200;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function aca(esto) {
            var esta = esto;
            alert(esta);
        }
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ajaxFunction(str) {
            var httpxml;
            try {
                // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
                httpxml = new XMLHttpRequest();
            } catch (e) {
                // Internet Explorer
                try {
                    httpxml = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
                } catch (e) {
                    try {
                        httpxml = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                    } catch (e) {
                        alert("Your browser does not support AJAX!");
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }

            function stateChanged() {
                if (httpxml.readyState == 4) {
                    document.getElementById("displayDiv").innerHTML = httpxml.responseText;

                }
            }
            var url = "search.php";
            url = url + "?txt=" + str;
            url = url + "&sid=" + Math.random();
            httpxml.onreadystatechange = stateChanged;
            httpxml.open("GET", url, true);
            httpxml.send(null);
        }
    </script>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        <form name="myForm">
            <input type="text" onkeyup="ajaxFunction(this.value);" name="username"
            />
            <div id="displayDiv"></div>
        </form>
    </body>
```

And this is the search.php

```
<?php
include ("dbinfo.php");
$in = $_GET['txt'];
$msg = "";
if (strlen($in) > 0 and strlen($in) < 20) {
    $t = mysql_query("select RubroId, RubroDisp from rubros where KeyWords like '$in%'");
    while ($nt = mysql_fetch_array($t)) {
        $valor = $nt[RubroDisp];
        $valorCodificado = str_replace(" ", "_", $valor);
        echo "<a href='#' onclick='aca($valorCodificado);'>$valor</a><br />";
        
                                        }
                                          }
?>
```

You can see the working page at [this url](http://www.gsilvainc.com/buscador)

Can you please tell me how to solve it? or what i am doing wrong?

thanks

Comment: Please indent your code!

Comment: I don't have any error in Chrome, be nice, write the complete error message here (with the line number if possible). Also tell us which browser your using.

Comment: This is the error i get with firebug: ReferenceError: Cerramientos_de_Aluminio is not defined
[Parar en este error]  

aca(Cerramientos_de_Aluminio);  code is indented, sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`aca($valorCodificado);` will generate JavaScript that calls a function with a variable (that probably doesn't exist) for the argument. It looks like you want a string there. Strings require quotes.